# tensorflow Protobuf Compilation issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, protoc

I want to compile protobuf libraries for google object detection API. I followed the official tutorial and typed `protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`. Then what I got is "object_detection/protos/*.proto: Invalid argument". Can anyone tell me what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: I solve this problem by compile the .proto files one by one. I think the problem is the *. I am using win10 system. But still wonder is there a way in windows that I can compile all the .proto files with one command. Compiling them one by one is too silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your operating system is windows, then *. may not work. A good way to solve this problem is to use bash. Download [git for windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win), don't forget to select git bash when you install it. 
From tensorflow/models/research/, right click, select git bash, then paste the command, it works well on my laptop.

Comment: to check if you have correctly protoced the proto files, go to the tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/protos, you will see many py scripts protoced from the proto files.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
protoc --python_out=. object_detection/protos/*.proto
```

Usage:

```
protoc [OPTION] PROTO_FILES
```

Comment: Probably shell (`cmd`?) doesn't expand `*.proto` to files. Try other shell or `protoc --python_out=. 1.proto 2.proto 3.proto`

Comment: That results in this for me: `File does not reside within any path specified using --proto_path (or -I).  You must specify a --proto_path which encompasses this file.  Note that the proto_path must be an exact prefix of the .proto file names -- protoc is too dumb to figure out when two paths (e.g. absolute and relative) are equivalent (it's harder than you think).`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but after some 20 minutes trying out different things, i decided to try it on another terminal and i tried it on git bash.

You need to be in the correct directory so just `cd` into `/models-master/research` and make a folder named `1prts` using `mkdir` once you are inside the `research` directory.

Since the last release, the repos has changed so this is the command you need to run:

```
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=./1prts
```