# protoc cannot find files in windows 7

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection

I'm trying to run the Object Detection high level API I found on Tensorflow github. One of the steps is to compile the module like this:

```
protoc object_detection\protos\*.proto --python_out=.
```

When I do that I get this message:

```
object_detection\protos\*.proto: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?
I'm running Windows 7

EDIT: if I run:

```
protoc --python_out=. *.proto
```

from the right folder, I get:

```
*.proto: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 7 cmd doesn't accept wildcard (*). This way, the *.proto doesn't match, because you don't have a file named `*.proto`.

If you want to apply `protoc --python_out=. filepath`, you have to use a `for` loop or issue the `protoc` manually for all files individually.

Comment: can you elaborate on this please :)

Comment: @RobiNoob Eddited my answer. I just had to do this myself.

Comment: Check this link to make a `for-loop` on cmd: https://ss64.com/nt/for.html

Answer (score 1):

The Symbol ' * '  is the problem. Sometimes windows does not recognize it.
So the best way to do it is by converting the proto files one by one.

**Best way to do it**

```
C:/Users/kc/Desktop/bin/protoc object_detection/protos/(file name in proto folder).proto --python_out=.
```

Since i have extracted my files to the desktop the above code is applicable to  me.

The above code will only work  when you have extracted your model file and (proto 3.4) bin file to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Try reviewing if your pwd is correct, perhaps python.exe is running on a different folder, where the subfolder object_detection doesn't exist, can you print the os.getcwd() and see if your program think it is where it should be, maybe you can also use os.chdir() to "enter" the folder or maybe you can simply use full path names.

Comment: Mmh not sure what you talking about. I'm running protoc from command line

Comment: you mean `cd`? I'm on W7. It prints out my project folder, it contains object_detection

Comment: does it work with a single file? maybe the asterisk is the problem

Comment: yeah I thught so. I tried with a single file and it looks like it finds it but then crashes for dependences, which is reasonable

Comment: I think bash on linux can handle asterisks properly, but cmd.exe on windows fails for asterisk, why not simply pass all the files like thids:

protoc folder/file1.proto folder/file2.proto etc, in order to simulate bash's wildcard expansion...

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me on Windows 10 in cmd:

`C:\your\path\tensorflow\models\research>“C:\your\path\protoc-3.4.0-win32\bin\protoc.exe” object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

If it executes without any error or message, then it worked.

I've used protoc version 3.4.0 for this process.

Referenced from this [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247921/tensorflow-object-detection-api-on-windows-error-modulenotfounderror-no-modu).