# Tensorflow Object Detection API on Windows - error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'"

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm attempting to get the TensorFlow Object Detection API

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

working on Windows by following the install instructions

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Which seem to be for Linux/Mac.  I can only get this to work if I put a script in the directory I cloned the above repo to.  If I put the script in any other directory I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

I suspect that the cause is not properly doing the Windows equivalent of this command listed on the install instructions above:

```
# From tensorflow/models/research/
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

I'm using Windows 10, Python 3.6, and TensorFlow 1.4.0 if that matters.  Of course, I've Googled on this concern and found various links, for example, this:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1747

But this has not resolved the concern.  Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Here are the steps I've done so far specifically:

---

### EDIT: these steps work now after updating to incorporate RecencyEffect's answer

1) Install TensorFlow and related tools via pip3

2) From an administrative command prompt, run the following:

```
pip3 install pillow
pip3 install lxml
pip3 install jupyter
pip3 install matplotlib
```

3) Clone the TensorFlow "models" repository to the Documents folder, in my case

```
C:\Users\cdahms\Documents\models
```

4) Downloaded Google Protobuf https://github.com/google/protobuf Windows v3.4.0 release "protoc-3.4.0-win32.zip" (I tried the most current 3.5.1 and got errors on the subsequent steps, so I tried 3.4.0 per this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku&index=1 and the protobuf compile worked)

5) Extract the Protobuf download to Program Files, specifically

```
"C:\Program Files\protoc-3.4.0-win32"
```

6) CD into the models\research directory, specifically

```
cd C:\Users\cdahms\Documents\models\research
```

7) Executed the protobuf compile, specifically

```
“C:\Program Files\protoc-3.4.0-win32\bin\protoc.exe” object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
```

Navigate to:

```
C:\Users\cdahms\Documents\models\research\object_detection\protos
```

and verify the .py files were created successfully as a result of the compile (only the .proto files were there to begin with)

8) cd to the object_detection directory, ex:

```
cd C:\Users\cdahms\Documents\models\research\object_detection
```

then enter the following at a command prompt to start the object_detection_tutorial.ipynb Jupyter Notebook

```
jupyter notebook
```

9) In the Jupyter Notebook, choose "object_detection_tutorial.ipynb" -> Cell -> Run all, the example should run within the notebook

10) In the Jupyter Notebook, choose “File” -> “Download As” -> “Python”, and save the .py version of the notebook to the same directory, i.e.

```
C:\Users\cdahms\Documents\models\research\object_detection\object_detection_tutorial.py
```

You can now open the script in your chosen Python editor (ex. PyCharm) and run it.

---

### EDIT per RecencyEffect's answer below, if you follow these additional steps you will be able to run the object_detection_tutorial.py script from any directory

11) Move the script to any other directory, then attempt to run it and you will find you will get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

because we have not yet informed Python how to find the utils directory that these lines use:

```
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
```

To resolve this . . .

12) Go to System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables . . . -> New, and add a variable with the name PYTHONPATH and these values:

[image]

13) Also under Environment Variables, edit PATH and add %PYTHONPATH% like so:

[image]

14) Reboot to make sure these path changes take effect

15) Pull up a command prompt and run the command "set", verify PYTHONPATH is there and PYTHONPATH and PATH contained the values from the previous steps.

16) Now you can copy the "object_detection_tutorial.py" to any other directory and it will run

Comment: Did you try adding `object_detection` to `PYTHONPATH` instead of `object_detection/utils`? Also, is the import in your code or in the object_detection code?

Comment: ?? OMG where was I on that one ??  Yes, I just added "C:\Users\cdahms\Documents\models\research\object_detection\utils" to PYTHONPATH as well and now it works.  If you post the same comment as an answer I'll accept it so you get credit, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the solution... it has been bothering me for hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, `utils` is a submodule so you actually need to add `object_detection` to `PYTHONPATH`, not `object_detection/utils`.

I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

cd Research/Object_Detection

cd ..

Research

1. export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

RESEARCH

2. git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

RESEARCH

3.export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim

4.protoc object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map.proto --python_out=.

CD OBJECT_DETECTION

5. protoc protos/string_int_label_map.proto --python_out=.

6.jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

The following command does not work on Windows:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

Instead, I followed the directions of this [tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10), which recommends setting the path variables for three different directories manually.  I simply added a path for the utils directory as well. So far it has worked without error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `__init__.py` file in your research/object_detection/protos folder! The `__init__.py` file is empty but needs to exist for the protos module to be created correctly.