# Import error: module object detection not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

When i try run code into Jupyter notebook i getting Import error(attached image).
I add paths to PYTHON_PATH and add %PYTHON_PATH% in system PATH, but i still get thos error 
[image: img]

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49126929/tensorflow-object-detection-api-on-windows-importerror-no-module-named-objec/50627405#50627405)

Comment: Where is `object_detection` installed, and what is the value of `sys.path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Anaconda**, you must know that it ignores `PYTHONPATH`!. Use the following commands:

`conda develop ~/models/research/`

`conda develop ~/models/research/slim/`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006114/anaconda-permanently-include-external-packages-like-in-pythonpath/37008663) is why you need to do it in this way. When you issue the above commands, it will create a `.pth` file inside your current's environment `site-packages` folder. Then, adds those two paths to this `.pth` file. Then, whenever you load your Anaconda prompt, those are on the path. This works for both Linux and Windows.