# Python (PyCharm) - Protoc is not a recognized command

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, protocol-buffers, object-detection, protoc

I realize there are other threads already, but none of the solutions are working for me. This is my error when trying to use the protoc command: [Protoc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4QCL.png).

I'm using Windows10 and a virtual environment in PyCharm using python 3.8 and pip is updated using the console command. 
I installed protobuf with pip and then I've manually downloaded protoc following the installation guide on https://grpc.io/docs/protoc-installation/.

I have tried both adding the path to the protoc.exe file in my venv path variables and copying it to Tensorflow/models/research, but neither yields a positive result.

I've tried both protoc-21.1-win64.zip and protobuf-python-4.21.1.zip. I added the path to the protoc.exe folder when using the win64 version but I'm not sure which folder contains the file for the python version, although I see most people recommend to use the windows version anyways.

Through my PyCharm terminal in my C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\Project_Name I'm attempting to run

`protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.`

I have tried to run it from C:\Users\Name\PycharmProjects\Project_Name\venv as well if that should make a difference.

These are the most prominent threads I've attempted solutions from:

[Cannot find `protoc` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929161/cannot-find-protoc-command)

[protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46491112/protoc-object-detection-protos-proto-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add the Protoc compiler to the path instead of adding it in PyCharm as that usually brings problems.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it! Every time I read to add it to path I just did it through PyCharm completely forgetting about how to do it through windows. This fixed it for me, thanks!