# Compile a folder of .profo files to multiple languages

Tags: python, swift, terminal, automation, protocol-buffers

Lets say I have a folder of some `.proto` files:

```
Message.proto
Conversation.proto
```

For every [.proto file for python](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial), I need to do this:

```
protoc --python_out=. XXXXXXX.proto
```

For every [.proto file for swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf), I need to do this:

```
protoc --swift_out=. XXXXXXX.proto
```

Is there any easy way to autocompile every .proto file to multiple languages in a folder? I have a lot of `.proto` files which I use for both languages, now I need to compile every file twice (for python and swift (but can you imagine the pain if I add more languages?)).

I am wondering what the fastest way there is to compile `.proto` files to multiple languages. Ideally, I want a generated folder of .swift/.py files of the .proto files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `protoc` in a shell, then you can use wildcards `*.proto` , like this:

```
protoc C:\your_absolute _path\*.proto --python_out=C:\python_source\
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949801/how-to-compile-multiple-proto-files-in-single-command)

If you need to support multiple languages, then you need to create script(or custom command) with a glob pattern what matches all the `*.proto` files in your build system, and run the command in a loop.

Just like the `add_custom_command` in `cmake` build system.

Answer (score 0):

Any traditional build system should be able to do this.

For example, Makefiles, scons, cmake or similar. The process is the same you would use to compile multiple `.c` files to multiple `.o` files with a C compiler, and there are plenty of examples for that.